# Retrigger mousewheel events from iframe

Tags: iframe, mousewheel

I want to re trigger the Mousewheel event of parent document form iframe document.Is it possible ? How can I achieve it?

Comment: I found the soultion:- We can bind the iframe mouse wheel to parent document mouse wheel. (e.g) this.bind(jQuery(document.getElementById("iframeid").contentDocument),"mousewheel",this.onmousewheel);

Comment: "this.bind"? o_O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the soultion with help of my friend:-
We can bind the iframe mouse wheel to parent document mouse wheel.

(e.g) this.bind(jQuery(document.getElementById("iframeid").contentDocument),"mousewhee‌​l",this.onmousewheel);

This will help only, if the two page in the same domain. Because javascript security policy doesn't allow the cross domain communication.